# Combinatorial probability: how often an element appears in a random set of $n$ elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A friend of mine asked me to help him with the following problem: basic probability calculus on a discrete set, but I need some confirmation whether my combinatorial considerations are OK.

> Let $\Omega$ contain $N$ elements, and let $f:\Omega\to\{0,1\}$. For any set $S\subset \Omega$ define the average of $f$ on the set $S$ by the formula
>   $$
>   a(S):=\frac{1}{\# S}\sum_{x\in S}f(x)
> $$
>   where $\#S$ is the cardinality of the set $S$. Suppose that $a(\Omega) = p$. Given that $S$ is chosen randomly and uniformly from sets that contain exactly $n$ elements, compute
>   $$
>   \mathsf Ea(S),\qquad \mathsf Ea^2(S).
> $$

My attempt is as follows: we pick $S$ out of the collection of $\binom Nn$ sets uniformly, so that
$$
  \mathsf Ea(S) = \frac{1}{n\binom Nn}\sum_S\sum_{x\in S}f(x).
$$
Each element $x$ in the sum above appears exactly the number of time, as many there are sets of the length $n$ that contain $x$ - that is $\binom{N-1}{n-1}$, thus
$$
  \mathsf Ea(S) = \frac{\binom {N-1}{n-1}}{n\binom Nn}\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = p\frac{N\binom {N-1}{n-1}}{n \binom Nn} = p\frac{N(N-1)!n!}{nN!(n-1)!} = p.
$$
For the case of the second moment, I similarly have
$$
  \mathsf Ea^2(S) = \frac{1}{n\binom Nn}\sum_S\sum_{x,y\in S}f(x)f(y).
$$
and now there are $\binom{N-1}{n-1}$ appearances of $f^2(x) = f(x)$ and $\binom{N-2}{n-2}$ appearances of $f(x)f(y)$ for $x\neq y$. Due to this reason
$$
  \mathsf Ea^2(S) = \frac{1}{n\binom Nn}\left(\binom{N-2}{n-2}\sum_{\stackrel{x,y\in X}{x\neq y}}f(x)f(y) + \binom{N-1}{n-1}\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\right)
$$
$$
  = \frac{1}{n\binom Nn}\left(\binom{N-2}{n-2}\left(\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\right)^2 + \left(\binom{N-1}{n-1} - \binom{N-2}{n-2}\right)\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\right)
$$
$$
  = \frac{1}{n\binom Nn}\left(N^2p^2\binom{N-2}{n-2} + Np\left(\binom{N-1}{n-1} - \binom{N-2}{n-2}\right)\right)
$$
which after simplification gives us
$$
  \mathsf Ea^2(S) = \frac{(Np^2 + p)(n-1)}{N-1} + p.
$$
I'd be happy to hear any feedback: whether the solution is correct, or whether it can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first quantity:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} a(S) &= \mathbb{E}\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{x\in S} f(x)= \mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in \Omega} f(x)\mathbb{1}_{\{x\in S\}} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in \Omega}f(x) \mathbb{E}\mathbb{1}_{\{x\in S\}} \tag{by linearity}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in \Omega}f(x) \mathbb{P}\{x\in S\}
\end{align*}
But since $S$ is chosen u.a.r. amongst all sets with $n$ elements, each $x\in \Omega$ belongs to $S$ with probability $\frac{|S|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{n}{|\Omega|}$; therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} a(S) 
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in \Omega}f(x) \frac{n}{|\Omega|} = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\sum_{x\in \Omega}f(x) = a(\Omega).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I would say though that $\mathbb P(x\in S) = \frac{|S|}{|\Omega|}$ is not completely obvious.